# Are there data dumps for other Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, data-dump

Are there data dumps for other Stack Exchange sites besides Stack Overflow?

Comment: Do you mean "other sites besides *Stack Overflow*"? Because I don't know of any Stack Exchange sites besides Stack Exchange...

Comment: Yes, I typed SE instead of SO. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you'd think the data dump exists only for SO:

> The latest version of the Stack Exchange Creative Commons Data Dump is now available. This reflects all public data in …
>
> - Stack Overflow
> - Server Fault
> - Super User
> - Stack Apps
> - all public non-beta Stack Exchange Sites
> - all corresponding meta sites

[source](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/creative-commons-data-dump-jan-11/)

Comment: Ah that's wonderful news. The reason why I thought it was restricted to SO is because I'd searched for the data dump before but only one site was mentionned. This is a good thing for perennity.