# Downloading a Stack Exchange site for NLP?

Tags: support, data-dump

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there data dumps for other Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92291/are-there-data-dumps-for-other-stack-exchange-sites)

Is it possible to download a copy of a recent image of a Stack Exchange site or database to use as a dataset (corpus) for [natural language processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing) (NLP) projects?  (I mean in some other way than spidering and scraping the site of course.) For example, see:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download

If this is not possible then I would like to make this a feature request. It should be relatively easy to setup a script that runs once-per-month to tar-up a database dump, or even just produce an XML document that concatenates the markdown from every Q&A page into a structured format. If the dataset was used a lot in the NLP community it would be good for Stack Exchange mindshare.

Comment: Found it I think: http://www.clearbits.net/torrents/2017-apr-2012  Is this all q&a from all SE sites?

Comment: Should be all up to that date